# Absolutely position an element inside a Column in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to create a calendar day view, like this (only take a look at a single day column):

[image: Google Calendar overview]

Here's my approach:

1. Draw a `LazyColumn` that renders the hours
2. Draw the event blocks and position them absolutely

Unfortunately I can't get this to run and couldn't find much information on this topic either. I managed to position the event block absolutely to the correct spot, but only with `Column` and the event block itself takes space up at the beginning of the `Column`, which makes it look like it uses a lot of margin at the top.

Here's my code and the result:

```kotlin
val CALENDAR_HOUR_HEIGHT = 200.dp;

@Composable
fun CreateScreen() {
    Box {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(
                rememberScrollState(),
            )
        ) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    // Example, move block to 2 hours
                    .absoluteOffset(y = CALENDAR_HOUR_HEIGHT * 2)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .background(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                    )
            )
            // Draw 24 hours lines
            repeat(24) {
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(CALENDAR_HOUR_HEIGHT)
                        .border(
                            width = 1.dp,
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                            shape = getBottomLineShape(3.dp.value),
                        )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

fun getBottomLineShape(bottomLineThickness: Float) : Shape {
    return GenericShape { size, _ ->
        // 1) Bottom-left corner
        moveTo(0f, size.height)
        // 2) Bottom-right corner
        lineTo(size.width, size.height)
        // 3) Top-right corner
        lineTo(size.width, size.height - bottomLineThickness)
        // 4) Top-left corner
        lineTo(0f, size.height - bottomLineThickness)
    }
}
```

Here's what it looks like, notice the big "margin" at the top, this is the event block taking up space:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you'll probably need some sort of custom layout. Maybe this will help?

https://danielrampelt.com/blog/jetpack-compose-custom-schedule-layout-part-1/

Android Developers also has some really good vids on drawing & layouts. Here's one I like:
https://youtu.be/1yiuxWK74vI, and also check out: https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/JetLagged

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).